# Can I host Wpf Ribbon control inside my Winform Application?

Tags: c#, wpf, ribbon-control

I have a `RibbonControl` built in WPF .

My question is, can I host Wpf Ribbon control inside a Windows form application and it is a bad thing or bad design to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done with [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx)

From my experience, the performance are not good but I used it to host a very complex control so maybe with lighter controls it will function better.
Here is your solution:
http://tech.pro/tutorial/799/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms

if you want to deepen your understanding, you can look here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx

also, you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751797%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more related info

Comment: Sadly the first link is no longer valid.